# For this probability is the Binomial Distribution more appropriate or just exponentiating the odds?

Tags: probability, statistics, binomial-distribution, robust-statistics

I have a somewhat of a unique problem, I am trying to determine the odds of the following,

**A Bernoulli Sequence where it follows the pattern of:** Tails, Tails, Tails, Tails, **Heads,** Tails, Tails, Tails, **Heads,** Tails, Tails, Tails, **Heads,** ..., ...

I want to find the probability of each position occurring in this sequence, I started with the Binomial Distribution, but realized that utilizing this actually gives me the probability of the number of heads anywhere within the sample; with this in mind I changed to doing the normal multiplication method of (0.5)^n.

**This would work normally except**, for each small segment of tails there can be an infinite amount before a head appears. So for example **this could also be a valid sequence:** Tails, Tails, Tails, Tails, **Heads,** Tails, Tails, Tails, Tails, Tails, Tails, Tails, **Heads,** ...

There needs to be at least three conesecutive tails in each tails section, but can go to an infinite amount. Any help with this would be appreciated. For the moment I am just working on the model of odds are <=(0.5)^n, n being the position in the series.

Comment: I don't understand what your question is.   Are you asking for the probability of a Bernoulli sequence having at least three consecutive tails separating each occurrence of heads?  If so, the probability of that happening for the *whole* sequence is zero.

Comment: I want multiple probabilities. For example I want the probability of the first position, then also the second position, then also the third position, then also the fourth postion, etc...